# XSD Validation in Java/or Groovy

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am receiving an error java.lang.StackOverflowError when trying to validate against a couple of schemas. Other Schema Validation tools such as XML Spy and MS VS XSD.exe validate the schemas.

Is there a specific limitation in Java that causes a sensitivity to such a setup?

Cheers,
Richard

Comment: What are you validating with? The build in Dom Parser, SAX parser? Have you tried the latest xerces jars?

Comment: I was validating with a hodgepodge of libraries. I've abandoned the approach I was taking initially as it was proving to be too time consuming. I will revisit at some point and update this issue if I uncover more specific info.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes XML validation just be very stack heavy. In Java it is often necessary to increase the stack size (using the "-Xss" JVM option) when you're using big/complicated schemas.